# Casperjs status fail on a Webpage

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Access to the link https://disqus.com/profile/login/ from Casperjs keeps returning the following

> [warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail:
>   https://disqus.com/profile/login/

**ensnare.js**

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.options.timeout = 15000;

casper.start("https://disqus.com/profile/login/", function() {
    this.echo("YES!", "GREEN_BAR");
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

**config.json**

```
{"ignoreSslErrors": true, "cookiesFile": "biscuit", "maxDiskCacheSize": 1000, "diskCache": true}
```

Please be informed that I changed "ignoreSslErrors" to false but it didn't work.

**Calling the script from the terminal**

```
./phantomjs --config=config.json casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js --casper-path=casperjs --cli ensnare.js
```

**Screenshot**

[image]
How go I about solving this problem? I am able to access other pages without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I needed to do was to have set "sslProtocol": "any" in the config.json file that I used. A proper way to set it can be found in my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894311/casperjs-windows-installation-how-is-it-done-the-correct-way-please/26649837#26649837).

Comment: If you are defining the setting in spookyjs, it's `"ssl-protocol": "any"`

Comment: I just run `casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true test FILE_NAME` and it works for me.

Answer (score 15):

try this (it helped me on Mac OS X):

```js
casperjs --debug=yes --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any XYZ.j
```

Where XYZ.js is your file.